# How to get access token expiration time in C#?

Tags: c#, api, controller, access-token, authorize

I have a C# controller api which is decorated with the `[Authorize]` attribute.

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult<int> GetAuthorizationDetails()
{
     var userIdentification = User.Claims; //this is part of System.Security.Claims ...
     var accessTokenDuration = ...; // Is there a way to catch the access token details?
}
```

The url above redirects me to the authentication site, where after logging in, I am redirected back to my website.

I know how to retrieve the user information which is in the claims --> `User.Claims`.

But it should also have a token which shows the token expiry time. Is there a way to read access token in C# --> something similar to `User.Claims` that retrieves the user information.

Thanks,

Comment: Is it not already in the claims?

Comment: Unfortunately no. It is not in the claims.

Comment: @avdeveloper have you checked the decoded token?

Comment: there should be field in payload with key "iat". You can get it like this

``var issuedAt = HttpContext.User.Claims.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Type == "iat");``

Comment: Usually, on the client, you just use the token. If you have 401, then you reissue the token and retry the request with a new one. Why do you need to know the expiration time?

Comment: @Neistow - am sorry but how do you check that? Regarding the "iat", I cannot find it in the claims.

Comment: @avdeveloper paste your token here and check payload https://jwt.io/